# Prefilled input that allows the user to add input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8, inertiajs

I have an input that I want to prefill with `https://` so all the user have to enter is the domain. Here's is the input

```
<div>
  <form-label for="form.website">Website</form-label>
    <form-input
      v-model="form.website"
      id="form.website"
      type="url"
      class="block w-full mt-1"
      placeholder="https://example.com"
    />
    <form-input-error
      class="block w-full"
      v-if="form.hasErrors && form.errors['website']"
      :message="form.errors['website']"
    />
  </div>
```

If I add to the value attribute I can't type pass the input value.
Thanks for the help. I'm using laravel with inertia and vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefill your field in data object:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {website: '' }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    web() {
      this.form.website = 'https://'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <label for="form.website">Website</form-label>
    <input
      v-model="form.website"
      id="form.website"
      type="url"
      class="block w-full mt-1"
      placeholder="https://example.com"
      @focus="web"
    />
  <form-input-error
    class="block w-full"
    v-if="form.hasErrors && form.errors['website']"
    :message="form.errors['website']"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to only show this on focus?

Comment: Hey mate, check now I updated answer

Comment: You are welcome mate, if you like pls upvote, cheers :)